# Taudem pit filling with threshold

Tags: taudem

Is it possible to fill pits in TauDEM up to a certain threshold (i.e. 1m depth)? In ArcGIS 'Fill Sinks', there is a tolerance parameter for this purpose, but there doesn't seem to be a similar parameter in TauDEM.

The purpose would be to retain sinks where they are 'real', but TauDEM blasts through all the pits in an elevation model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TauDEM does not currently have this functionality directly implemented.

You could achieve the result with a bit of iteration.  First fill pits using the TauDEM function.  Then take the difference between the filled and original DEM.  Identify locations where this difference grid is greater than the threshold you want to use and construct a depression mask grid that has values of 1 in these locations and 0 (or anything else) elsewhere.  Then use that as a depression mask input to the pitremove function and you should get a result where these pits are excluded from the filling.

There is of course the option of adding this functionality to the code in github and if you do this and make a pull request against the original repository I will evaluate this and could include it in a future release.